# WPF : Adding Border to an image programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to add a style to the the image programmatically. Here is my code

```
<UserControl.Resources>
       <Style x:Name="BranchPages" x:Key="BranchPages">
            <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Green">
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

and the code behid is as follows

```
  Style greenbdr = (Style)FindResource("BranchPages");
  page.img.Style = greenbdr;
```

But Its not working Please help

Comment: Could you please tell what exactly you want to achieve? Having green border on hover or something else?

Comment: Its on the load event of the image. 
Actually after applying the style, I am displaying the page.img Image

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This workaround might help:

Since the Image has no border, place it inside a Border control.

```
<Border Name="imgBorder" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Transparent">
        <Image Name="img"></Image>
</Border>
```

Then create logic code against the properties of that Border.

```
imgBorder.BorderBrush = Brushes.Green;
```

Answer (score 0):

An Image is not a Control, it is only derived from FrameworkElement and thus has no Template property.
It has a Style, though, so you can use it to set its properties, like Cursor, HorizontalAlignment, etc.